# Doctrine ManyToMany - join multiple relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm wondering if there is a way to get records from one table using 2 ManyToMany relations (it's probably easier to explain that with an example).

I've got 3 models: Article, Topic and Type and there is a relation ManyToMany between Article <-> Topic and Article <-> Type and what I'm looking for is to get Types for Articles which are assigned to certain Topic. I hope that this make sense.

Below you can see declaration of my entities:

```
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var topics
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Topic")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="article_topic")
     */
    protected $topics;

    /**
     * @var types
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Type", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="article_type")
     */
    protected $types;
}  

class Topic
{
    /**
     * @var Article
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article")
     */
    private $articles;
}

class Type
{
    /**
     * @var Article
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article")
     */
    private $articles;
}
```

Now in my TypeRepository i have a method: **(UPDATED)**

```
public function getByTopic($topic = null)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('t')
        ->from('Type', 't');

    if ($topic) {
        $subqb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('a.id')
            ->from('Article', 'a')
            ->innerJoin('a.topics', 'atop', 'WITH', 'atop.id = :topicId')
        ;
        $qb->innerJoin('t.articles', 'ta')
            ->where($qb->expr()->in('ta.id', $subqb->getDql())
            ->setParameter('topicId', $topic->getId());
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

and I get an error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected (but it's showing me the line from twig template and I'm struggling to get to the bottom of this).

The questions is how to get Types assigned to articles which belongs to certain topic.

Any suggestions appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing something like this :

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('ty')  
                         ->addSelect('ty');  
if ($topic) {  
  $qb->join('ty.articles','a')  
     ->addSelect('a')  
     ->join('a.topics','to')  
     ->addSelect('to')  
     ->where('to.id=:topic_id')  
     ->setParameter('topic_id',$topic);
}
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```